# EKS Load Balancer slowness using Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, nginx, amazon-eks

EKS Slowness:
All, I have an EKS cluster running and I am using nginx Ingress controller with Classic LB. However, while accessing the LB, it is too dead slow ( Not all the requests, but only a couple of requests ). I have the LB in the public subnet and my EC2 Instances are in the private subnet. And my public subnets also have the elb tag as well. Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Install the [AWS Load Balancer Controller](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/) and use it to create an NLB for your NGINX ingress service. NLB is more performant than the Classic Load Balancer.

Comment: I did try provisioning the NLB without the AWS Load Balancer controller, using the Service Annotation. And the performance was still the same, I still see the requests getting delayed by 60 sec or more. Will the AWS LB Controller make any difference?

Comment: Use the LB controller with TargetType IP instead of instance. That will bypass kube-proxy.

Comment: But will this configuration cause a delay of 2 minutes and sometimes it doesn't connect at all?

Comment: Not at all. Traffic will be routed directly from the load balancer to the pod IP.